# Customize MobaXterm color scheme

Tags: shell, vim, colors

I am using a CentOS via VNC and the using vim editor, where the color scheme looks something like this..

[image]

What is the name of this color scheme ? Where I can get the properties of the same ?

In Windows 7, I am using MobaXterm and want to use the same color scheme shown above.

Using Settings->Configuration->Terminal->Default color scheme->Customize  option, how I can configure the above color scheme in MobaXterm ?

Answer (score 2):

Type `:colorscheme` and Vim will output the name of the colorscheme. You can then use `:colorscheme <name>` to set this (for the current session, persistent by placing the command in your `~/.vimrc`).

If the colorscheme is installed on one computer, but not the other, you can search the `:scriptnames` output for the full path of the colorscheme. Then, copy and place the script into `~/.vim/colors/` on the other computer.

In a terminal, you don't need to adapt the terminal's colors. Vim colorschemes use the available colors, some support only 16, but many today (also) have 256-color palettes. Check with `:set t_Co?` to see how many colors your terminal support.

Answer (score 0):

Mobaxterm alters colors as developers saw to fit, I.e. colors it renders has nothing to do with colors used. Sadly there is no "preserve" setting.